# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text', but text is on page

Tags: python, error-handling, beautifulsoup, attributes

I have been trying sseveral differnet ways to get a price value from a page using this code:

```
    import requests
headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept_Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept_Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade_Insecure_Requests": "1",
    "User_Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
    }
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#write a CSV file
with open("/Users/eezar/Desktop/reverbsolid.csv","w",newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Guitar","Price"])
#get the URL of target page
    pages=[]
    for n in range(1,5,1):
        url=("https://reverb.com/marketplace/electric-guitars/solid-body?page={}".format(n))
    #create string for URL
        r = requests.get(url)
    # get the HTML parser
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        [s.extract() for s in soup('sup')]
    #identify the parent tag/container for the information
        products = soup.find_all('ul', class_ = 'tiles tiles--four-wide tiles--sidebar-width')
    #loop through container - give a name for the individual component e.g. title.  Text.strip take out the text
        for title in products:
            Guitar = soup.find('img', alt=True)
            Price = soup.find('span',{'class' : 'price-display'}).text.strip()
            #write each line to the CSV using the loop
            print(Guitar)
            writer.writerow ([Guitar,Price])
```

But I get this error:

```
File "reverbsolid.py", line 32, in <module>
    Price = soup.find('span',{'class' : 'price-display'}).text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I can see the value in text in the page code:

```
> <span class="price-display"><!-- react-text: 1023 -->$450<!--
> /react-text --></span>
```

Don't know what to try next?

Comment: Are you sure that element exists? What does the html look like?

Comment: That must mean that `soup.find('span',{'class' : 'price-display'})` is returning None. I don't have any experience with BeautifulSoup, but it would appear your CSS accessor is wrong.

Comment: Great read: [How to debug small programs (#1)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) - set a breakpoint and inspect the content before the error occures - or at least put in some print statements to see if the tag you are looking for does exist.

Comment: Just checked the page source, the data is loaded with javascript, try using selenium to emulate a browser and extract the data

Comment: Oh boy...yes the source code just shows; <div class="listing-card__price" data-reactid="59">

Comment: @Stack can I embed that into my code?

Comment: yes selenium works with python, check `http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/`

Comment: note that this: `[s.extract() for s in soup('sup')]` is not saved to anywhere either

Comment: Great, thank you @Stack I'll get onto that now - thanks for the pointer!

Comment: happy to help :D

Comment: @patrick, that line is for removing the tags. It doesn't need to be saved in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly modified version of your code that I used to achieves the same result:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept_Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept_Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade_Insecure_Requests": "1",
    "User_Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
}


# write a CSV file
with open("reverbsolid.csv","w",newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Guitar","Price"])
    # get the URL of target page
    pages=[]
    for n in range(1,5,1):
        url=("https://reverb.com/marketplace/electric-guitars/solid-body?page={}".format(n))
        # create string for URL
        r = requests.get(url)
        # get the HTML parser
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        # get all products
        container = soup.find('ul', class_ = 'tiles tiles--four-wide-max')
        products = container.find_all('li', class_ = 'tiles__tile')
        # loop through container - give a name for the individual component e.g. title.  Text.strip take out the text
        for product in products:
            print(product)
            Guitar = product.find('img', alt=True)
            Price = product.find('span',{'class' : 'price-display'}).text.strip()
            #write each line to the CSV using the loop
            print(Guitar)
            writer.writerow ([Guitar,Price])
```

This results in:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

If we look into one of the products:

```
<li class="tiles__tile">
  <div class="grid-card grid-card--placeholder">
    <div class="grid-card__inner">
      <div class="grid-card__main">
    <div class="grid-card__image"></div>
    <div class="grid-card__main__text">
      <div class="grid-card__title"></div>
    </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-card__footer">
    <div class="grid-card__footer__pricing">
      <div class="grid-card__price">
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

We can see there is no title or price. The reason for this is that this page is using javascript to populate the DOM and `requests` will not run the javascript for you so all you have are empty product slots. If you want something like that the easiest way will be to use something like `selenium` (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) that will run a full browser for you.

There is an easier way to get the info you want in this case, however. All of the raw item data is contained in a `meta` tag called `apollo-state`. So:

```
import csv
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept_Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept_Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Upgrade_Insecure_Requests": "1",
    "User_Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
}


# write a CSV file
with open("reverbsolid.csv","w",newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["Guitar","Price"])
    # get the URL of target page
    pages=[]
    for n in range(1,5,1):
        url=("https://reverb.com/marketplace/electric-guitars/solid-body?page={}".format(n))
        # create string for URL
        r = requests.get(url)
        # get the HTML parser
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
        container = soup.find('meta', {'name': 'apollo-state'})
        container = container['content']
        container = json.loads(container)
        # parse products here
```

Working with the `container` dictionary here should give you the prices.

Note: I would've gone with a `selenium` solution here, because it's more intuitive even if slower to execute.